# SQL merge results from two tables into single row

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables that differ by 1 column and want to get results in 1 row when a column value matches in both tables.

The columns of interest in the tables are: num, tier and count

The queries are:
select tier, count from TABLE_1 where num=1 order by tier

```
tier  count
0     10
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
```

select tier, count from TABLE_2 where num=1 order by tier

```
tier  count
0     1
1     4
2     10
```

Using "inner join" will return rows from both tables but for each row in table_1, there are 3 rows, each one corresponding to row in table_2.

```
select   p.tier, p.count, b.tier, b.count from TABLE_1 p
inner  join TABLE_2 b b 
on p.num = b.num 
where p.num=1 
order by p.tier

0    10   1    4  -\
0    10   0    1    |  3 rows of table_2
0    10   2    10 -/
1    1    1    4  -\
1    1    0    1    |   3 rows of table_2
1    1    2    10 -/
2    1    0    1  -\
2    1    1    4    |   3 rows of table_2
2    1    2    10 -/
:
etc
```

I want the result to be table_1 tier/count table_2 tier/count

```
0     10   0  1
1     1    1  4
2     1    2  10
3     1    3  0 
4     1    4  0
```

Note that table_2 tier is not necessary but it needs to have count as 0 if there is no corresponding row in table_2 for the tier.

Comment: Try a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: What's the expected result if table2 has a row without match in table1?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a simple left join and coalesce.

```
SELECT
    t1.tier,
    COALESCE(t1.count, 0) AS t1_count,
    COALESCE(t2.tier, t1.tier) AS t2_tier,
    COALESCE(t2.count, 0) AS t2_count
FROM TABLE_1 t1 LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 t2
ON
    t1.num = t2.num AND t1.tier = t2.tier
ORDER BY
    t1.tier;
```

Answer (score 0):

perfect - thanks!

but the last one should have condition for t1.num = 1 :)

```
ON
    t1.num = t2.num AND t1.tier = t2.tier
    where t1.num = 1
```

... but if there are more rows in table2 than in table1, result returns only the rows for table1.